# Depend Vs. Become / get dependent

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please imagine a girl that has recently gone through some emotional problems which occured between she and her boyfriend; they are about to break up now, but they have not cut ties yet! The girl feels so depressed and opens her heart to a wise friend who had experienced ups and downs of life!
In order to avoid emotional damages, the friend is fiving some advices now:

> - Whereas a girl is more sensitive and emotional most of the times, it is not surprising that she **depends / becomes dependent / gets dependent** more quickly!

The girl accepts her friend's statement and says:

> - Yes! My mom warned my: **don't depend on him that much** / **don't become dependent on him that much** / **don't get dependent on him that much**.

My question is that which one of the similar bold alternatives  above sound natural and idiomatic on my scenario? 
I'm asking this question because when I was surfing on the Internet I couln't find any hit about it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To depend sb on oneself](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203510/to-depend-sb-on-oneself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "that much" works very well in any of your sentences, so I suggest

> Don't depend on him too much.
>
> Don't become too dependent on him.

Comment: thank you very much for your informative response; just in order to reassure me, I would appreciate it if you let me know whether according to what you mentioned, these sentences sound natural and idiomatic: **(A girl becomes dependent so quickly)** = **(A girl depend so quickly)**

Comment: The first is OK, not the second.

Comment: thank you, but may I know why? Maybe just because of the missing "s" after "depend"!

Comment: Not just that, but the verb has no object. The girl depends **on** something.